# In R, using the ggplot2 package how can I plot 4 graphs on 2 columns and 2 rows?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to graph 4 graphs separately but instead of plotting them all side by side or on top of each other, I would like to plot 2 graphs on one row and the last two on another row. The problem I have with this is that I am using the `fact_grid` command in the `ggplot2` package to try to do this but the factor argument that I am passing in to the `facet_grid` command has 4 levels. So right now my code specifically for the `facet_grid` command looks like:

```
facet_grid(. ~ type)
```

If I try to change the code and put 2 instead of the `.` in the code above, then I get an error saying `undefined columns selected`. So I was wondering if anyone knew how to get these 4 factor levels to show up separately on 2 different rows and columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about facet_wrap() with nrow=2 rather than facet_grid?